# Loop through comma separated values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a Master DB.
I want to make duplicate DB of the Master DB but not all tables just specified.

I have those table names in comma separated string.
`tbl1, tbl2, tbl7, tbl10` etc.

I'm trying to make a stored procedure passing it `new DB name` That creates the DB and replicate the given table to it. So far i have 2 thing, but i don't know how to loop through it. I'm new to DB so please guide how to achieve this.

(**Note**) *I haven't found if an array can be used to loop through, the table names could also be stored in array variable, because the table names are hard coded.*

The following is the sudo code i desire.

```
CREATE DATABASE %param_db%;

@tables = 'tbl1, tbl2, tbl7, tbl10';
loop through @tables as table_name
    CREATE TABLE %param_db.table_name% LIKE Master.%table_name%;
End loop
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps to layout in the Stored Procedure

- Create the Target database
- Determine how many elements are in the list of tables
- Loop through each element of the list of tables using the [**ELT() function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_elt)
- Take each element and form SQL Statement to create the new table in Target DB

Here is that Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`TableCookieCutter` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`TableCookieCutter`
(
    SourceDB VARCHAR(64),
    TargetDB VARCHAR(64),
    TableList VARCHAR(1024)
)
BEGIN

    # Create the Target DB
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ',TargetDB);
    PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

    # Strip Table List of Blanks
    # Enclose each table in quotes
    SET @table_list = CONCAT('''',REPLACE(REPLACE(TableList ,' ',''),',',QUOTE(',')),'''');

    # Count the number of tables in the list
    SET @table_stub = REPLACE(@table_list,',','');
    SET @array_count = LENGTH(@table_list) - LENGTH(@table_stub) + 1;

    # Loop through list of tables, creating each table
    SET @x = 0;
    WHILE @x < @array_count DO
        SET @x = @x + 1;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ELT(',@x,',',@table_list,') INTO @tb');
        PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',TargetDB,'.',@tb,' LIKE ',SourceDB,'.',@tb);
        PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
    END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA for this answer which has been quite helpful to me. Now, I have a similar need to iterate over a comma-separated list in a `trigger`. Using this approach gives an obvious error about dynamic SQL being forbidden in a trigger. I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806998/loop-through-comma-separated-list-in-a-mysql-trigger

Answer (score 2):

@RolandoMySQLDBA post it first, but I have another way.

Using this to [split comma string separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row) and [this for the number of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field), I've made this Stored Procedure:

### STORED PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spCreateRplDB`(
IN iNewDB VARCHAR(100),
IN iOldDB VARCHAR(100),
IN iTables VARCHAR(150))
BEGIN
# Comma separated string
SET @repldb=iNewDB;
SET @masterdb=iOldDB;
SET @tbls=TRIM(iTables);
SET @counter=(SELECT ROUND((LENGTH(@tbls) - LENGTH( REPLACE (@tbls, ",", ""))) / LENGTH(",")));
SET @loop_num=0;
# Splitting comma separated string
IF (@counter>0 && @repldb<>'' && @masterdb <> '') THEN
    SET @counter=@counter+1; # [ ADDING +1 BECAUSE @counter JUST COUNT THE NUMBER OF OCCURENCES OF A STRING INSIDE @tbls ]
    # Creating DB if not exists
    SET @database_create=CONCAT(" CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ",@repldb,";");
    PREPARE database_create FROM @database_create;
    EXECUTE database_create;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE database_create;

    WHILE @loop_num<>@counter DO
        SET @loop_num=@loop_num+1; 
        SET @rownumber=0; # Row Number
        SET @tbl='';
        SELECT 
            v.value 
        INTO @tbl
        FROM (SELECT 
                    TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.value, ',', n.n), ',', -1)) AS value,
                    @rownumber:=@rownumber+1 AS rownumber
                FROM (SELECT @tbls AS value) AS t 
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
                            FROM 
                            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
                           ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
                                ORDER BY n
                            ) n
                WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.value, ',', ''))) 
                HAVING rownumber=@loop_num) AS v;
        # Creating Table
        SET @drop_table=CONCAT(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ",@repldb,".",@tbl,";");
        SET @create_table=CONCAT(" CREATE TABLE ",@repldb,".",@tbl," LIKE ",@masterdb,".",@tbl,";");
        # Preparing STMT for @drop_table
        PREPARE droptable FROM @drop_table;
        EXECUTE droptable;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE droptable;
        # Preparing STMT for @create_table
        PREPARE create_table FROM @create_table;
        EXECUTE create_table;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_table;
    END WHILE;
END IF;
END
```

### PROCESSES:

1. `@counter`, number of occurrences of `,` (*tables delimiter*).
2. If there's more than 0 occurrences and `iNewDB` and `iOldDB` is not null or empty then continue.
3. Create the new database (*iNewDB*).
4. Creating new tables with the number of inputs in the `iTables` parameter.

### TEST:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
| test_old           |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES IN test_old;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_test_old |
+--------------------+
| test1              |
| test2              |
| test3              |
| test4              |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> CALL test.spCreateRplDB(
    -> 'test_dev', # New DB
    -> 'test_old', # Master DB
    -> 'test1,test2,test4');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
| test_dev           |
| test_old           |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES IN test_dev;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_test_dev |
+--------------------+
| test1              |
| test2              |
| test4              |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```